# individual axis label color with Dygraphs 2.2.1 in multiple graphs

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

Using CSS setting up a color for y-label or y2-label as described at dygraphs CSS reference works very well, example:
`.dygraph-ylabel{ color:green; } .dygraph-y2label{ color:blue; }`

This setting seems to be global to a html-page and the graphs therein.
If there are multiple graphs within a html-page the label colors set through CSS are the same for all.

Using some call in the java-script part of the html-page within g0.ready changes color of all label for a graph, in this call.
`document.getElementById("g0").style.color = "black";`
The same works when implemtented in g1.ready-section using a different color.
I like to set the colors for each axis label: xlabel, ylabel, y2label separate within each graph.
Several variants of the above call have been tried, but didn't find a way.

This, and varinats of it, give an error, it seems that dygraph-ylabel is incorrect: `document.getElementById("g0").style.color.dygraph-ylabel = "green";`

Is there a way to set the label colors for individual axes separate for each grafics instance?

Comment: Here some sample using jsfiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Rudi_Bee/hL04rszk/1/

The javascipt code is in the html, be cause there are multiple javascript sections:
you may find the call to change a label color within the dygraphs ready part of the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can scope styles to an individual chart using CSS selectors. The [descendant combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_combinator), aka space, is useful here:

```css
/* this applies to all charts */
.dygraph-ylabel {
  color: green;
}

/* this only applies to #g0 */
#g0 .dygraph-ylabel {
  color: green;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
Somehow this doesn't do the job.
This is what I tried, none of them changed a color; [fiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/Rudi_Bee/hL04rszk/19/)
`````
g0 .dygraph-ylabel {
  color: green;
}
g0 .dygraph-label.dygraph-y2label {
  color: blue;
}
g1 dygraph-label.dygraph-ylabel {
  color: yellow;
}
g1 dygraph-y2label {
  color: red;
}
````

Comment: You need to use `#` to indicate an ID in CSS: `#g0`, not `g0`. Make sure the IDs in your CSS match the IDs in your JavaScript: https://jsfiddle.net/o14gn6w7/1/

Comment: Thanks a lot, 
works as you wrote. 
I missed: The css needs to go with the div the dygraph is in.
Update this  [jsfiddle.net/Rudi_Bee/hL04rszk/21/](https://jsfiddle.net/Rudi_Bee/hL04rszk/21/)